# Angular mat-table with additional row before each group

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to create layaut similar to this one with Angular Material

[image]

I don't know how to add additional header row (blue one) before each group of rows.

This is what I have so far.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<ng-container matColumnDef="env">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Env </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.options.env}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

My data has layout:

```
{ [{options: {env: abc}, sublist: {[host1, host2, hostn]}}, ..]}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's the way to do this (really need 4 more characters to post this?) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-groupheader?file=package.json

Comment: it help me lot . THank you